# NoSuchMethod SmsMessage <init>?

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm attempting to run apps on an emulator and I'm experiencing some strange crashes, e.g.:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.telephony.SmsMessage.<init>
```

Certainly this should more or less be standard? Is this potentially a version error? I'm running on API 15; I believe the apk in question was built to an older version, although I don't know which (I'm in the process of installing and testing on older API versions).

Any thoughts on what could be going on here / approaches to get around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<init>` stands for constructor, but if you'll take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) you'll realize, it has no constructor (actually it has, but it is `private`, take a look [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/jb-mr1-dev/src/java/android/telephony/SmsMessage.java)), so you can't do something like that:

```
SmsMessage smsMessage = new SmsMessage();
```

**EDIT** The confusion is coming from the fact, that there are 2 versions of `SmsMessage`:

1. The [first one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsMessage.html) is coming from `android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage`, was added at API level 1, but is deprecated since API level 4 and it has public constructor.
2. The [second one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) is coming from `android.telephony.SmsMessage` and replaces the version above since API level 4.

So, because you are getting such error, you imported the newest one `android.telephony.SmsMessage` and the code should be re-written to fit newer version of class.

Comment: and yet an app that at one point ran apparently does this? I did not write the app I am testing, and it has been successfully used by others.